# Django objects.all() making 360+ queries - how can I optimise this ManyToMany?

Tags: django

New to Django, third question on it today...

I have the following (simplified) models defined:

```
class Band(models.Model):
    bandname = models.CharField('Band name', max_length=300)

class Release(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    artist = models.ManyToManyField('Band')
    formats = models.ManyToManyField('Format')

class Format(models.Model):
    kind = models.CharField(max_length=300)

class Song(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    release = models.ForeignKey('Release')
```

(I've removed extra fields for the sake of readability)

Now, when I try to run the following query, it adds hundreds of extra queries to the page:

```
s = Song.objects.all() # adds 367 queries
```

I've tried changing it to this:

```
s = Song.objects.select_related('band', 'release').all() # adds 245 queries
```

This still sucks and I don't know what else I can do. There are 122 songs in my database, on 52 releases, by 39 bands. Not sure if this helps but I'm at a loss.

Any tips on how to optimise this? I need to be able to show the band and release name for each `Song`. A `Release` is ManyToMany for `Band` because some of them are split releases by multiple artists.

thanks,
Matt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Django `select_related` does not follow many-to-many relationships, and I'm guessing that is what is causing the large query count.

My suggestion is to use `values()`, and `double__underscore__notation` to get the required values. Something similar to this should work on django 1.3 and above:

```
s = Song.objects.values('title', 'release__title', 'release__artist__bandname')
```

Comment: Thanks for this - almost works. I get: `Invalid field name: 'release__artist__bandname'` - I can confirm these are the correct field names.

Comment: Oh right, it's a many to may field. Hmm I might have to rethink my solution. I guess this one was not well though out. I have never really used double-underscore with many-to-many field. That is something that I'll have to look into.

Comment: I have a method within `Release` that returns a comma separated string list of `Artists`, but I can't seem to use this either... hmm. So close!

Comment: This might still not work but I was not sure if I should use 'release__artist__bandname' or 'release___band__name'. In any case depending on the number of bands you have your result set would be very large.

Comment: release___band__name just errors with "Cannot resolve keyword 'release___band__name' into field. Choices are: filename, id, is_featured, release, title". 

Would it make more sense to run a separate query for artists (and/or releases) and merge them with songs? Or maybe just write some pure SQL...

Comment: If a release will not be associated with too much band, which might be the case, writing some SQL to give one result set seem best in terms of speed. Merging them is not a bad idea either, but I would probably lean more to Using SQL in this case even though I don't really like writing SQL. Hopefully someone can give a better answer.

Comment: Hey, managed to fix it - changed the ManyToMany to a ForeignKey instead. Guess I'll have to live with it...